# c# interop find and replace text inside table

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I need to replace placeholders in my .dotx document with provided values and then print that document.
Everything is working only problem is that placeholders inside tables are not replaced.If it is outside of table it is replaced but if I put it in table (which I need to format correctly final document) it stays unchanged.

```
public static void FindReplace(string var1, string var2, string[] Stranke)   
{
            
    Word.Word.Application app = new Word.Word.Application();
    app.ActivePrinter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cfg_PrinterOmoti"];
    Word.Word.Document doc = null;

    object template = "C:\\template1.dotx";
 
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    doc = app.Documents.Open(template, missing, missing);
    
    app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
    app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

    app.Selection.Find.Execute("<PLACEHOLDER_1>", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,missing, var1);

    app.Selection.Collapse();
    app.Selection.Find.Execute("<PLACEHOLDER_2>", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, var2);
```

there is more code but I think it is irrelevant as from this point  it starts to print and close document.

Comment: Did you try to pass the argument that accepts `Word.WdReplace` with the value `Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;`

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure where to pass this argument? Can you be just little more specific. It is probably obvious but I don't see where and how to do it. Sorry